# Response string cut in Retrofit 2

Tags: java, rx-java, retrofit2

I'm using Retrofit 2 and I have a service REST `GET` method. This service returns an URL but the response string is cut after `https`

Example response:

```
'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask'
```

and my string has

```
'http'
```

Code:

```java
@GET(BuildConfig.ENDPOINTPIC)
Observable<String> getUrlUpload(@Query("mk")String mk,@Query("pk")String pk);
```

Comment: response is just a single string? no JSON?

Comment: its correct @MuraliPrajapati

Comment: What is your converter factory?

Comment: You could try to use `Observable<ResponseBody>` and access the string from the ResponseBody object. I suspect the converter is at fault here too.

Comment: thanks @peitek i use ResponseBody.string and work fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution** User :  @peitek

Use `ResponseBody`

```
 @GET(BuildConfig.ENDPOINTPIC)
    Observable<ResponseBody> getUrlUpload(@Query("mk")String mk,@Query("pk")String pk);
```